# Using Mesa3d with C++ in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opengl, mesa

I'm doing an OpenGL course but only have integrated graphics with my Intel processor. Upon doing some research it seems I can use the Mesa implementation of OpenGL with my integrated graphics.

On the installation page it says it requires python, but my course will be practicing OpenGL in a C++ environment.

I've also been looking at OpenGL tutorials online in C++, and there are many libraries used for simplifying common tasks in OpenGL. Will I be able to use these libraries with Mesa in C++, and if so, how would I approach this?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the Mesa website states that you need python to **build** Mesa.

Comment: I'm mostly on windows, but I'm pretty sure the few times I did OpenGL on linux I used essentially the same code (granded SDL did the window abstraction for me, but the rest was essentially unchanged, and it yes it was C++ code, the OGL headers were generated using glLoadGen).

Comment: Instead of installing Mesa yourself, just use your package manager.  In fact, there's a very good chance it's already installed.  Run `sudo apt install mesa-utils`, then you can run `glxinfo`.  Run `glxinfo | grep 'direct rendering'` to check that hardware acceleration is supported, and run `glxinfo | grep 'version string'` to see the version of OpenGL supported.

Comment: Great, it's up and running, thanks guys

Comment: Do I refer to pkg-config when compiling or are there header files I use with @DietrichEpp's installation?

Comment: How would I use the Glut package? Sorry, very new to C++

Comment: Install the `freeglut3-dev` package, link with `-lglut`, and `#include <GL/glut.h>`.